# How to gain the time lord hat (winter bash)

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

For the new *Winter Bash* feature I've seen a *time lord* hat that is an image of the *Tardis* (from *Doctor Who* show). In the description it says that it is a secret.

If it's not abuse, I would like to know how to get it.

**EDIT**

The secret was unveiled (and not downvoted but indeed rewarded with eureka hat): https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245270

Comment: You have to gift a goat to the satan.

Comment: To the sontaran, you mean...

Comment: Sontar-ha! Sontar-ha!

Comment: how can I get the eureka hat then?

Comment: Here it is explained http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245170/winter-bash-2014-secret-hats/245270#245270

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The secret hats are being discussed here:

[Winter Bash 2014 Secret Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245170/winter-bash-2014-secret-hats)

The tardis can be obtained by editing old posts.
The exact details are unknown as of yet, but I believe you should target questions, rather than answers.

Comment: Ok, so all the downvotes to my question are inappropiate. Thanks, I accept your answer as it adds value to the question.

Comment: Cool, I got one and had no idea why ;p Guess time is a bit of hint.

Answer (score 13):

Secret hat is secret.

That means no telling.

Comment: Ok, I think that public jokes are more enjoyable than private-public jokes. Anyway I don't pretend to abuse so I'll accept your answer (in 11 minutes it sais).